# Can I set the value of an ID column in SQL server with an insert?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

If I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

Is it possible to insert my own test data and override the identity column? The reason I am asking is because I have several tables I need to populate like this and I want to get the ID columns in each to match foreign keys?

If this is not possible then could I insert data and then later change it to an identity column? If anyone can give me an example how to do that I would be very happy.

Comment: Yes, turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` for that table and you'll be able to insert into the ID column (remember to turn it off again afterwards!)

Comment: I am sorry but how do I turn it on and off and then how would I add it later with a different start value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application ON

INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name)
VALUES (3, 'Third Row')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application OFF
```

Comment: be sure to run DBCC CHECKIDENT( <table_name>, RESEED ) afterwards to reset the next seed value for the table

Comment: @qujck - How does this work?

Comment: @Anne Running that command (the one posted by qujck) will allow you to change where the new identities will start from when you are doing normal identity inserts.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application ON

[Do your insert]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application OFF
```